# How to start a New Game Plus?

Tags: infinity-blade

How do you start a New Game Plus in Infinity Blade?  I see it mentioned on walkthroughs, but no one ever details how to achieve it.  Moreover, it seems to be a necessary prerequisite to mastering items more than once.

I've never seen it come up as an option, either in the game itself or through the Options menu.  FWIW, I'm at level 40, and I've defeated the God King three times.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start a New Game+ by beating the end boss in the dungeon (accessible by moving to the open hatch, just before the door to the castle). Once inside, if you have the Infinity Blade you'll unlock more of the dungeon, eventually getting to the end boss. Once you defeat him, the game gives you the option of starting a new bloodline or doing New Game+.

Update: I originally posted that you could start a New Game+ any time in the Options. However, I've had a chance to start the game up but I couldn't find anything there that indicates this. I also searched online, and was unable to find anything there as well.